# How can Blake2X produce 4gb digests?

Tags: hash

I assume the state is not 4Gb but that there's a 32bit counter and it's mixing like in chacha. What's the point of creating those 4Gb if there's no entropy to do so. What I mean is that if the first 1024 bits are the same, so would the rest of the 4Gb, so why even offer the option.

Comment: There is a need for XOF (eXtendeable Output Functions) in Cryptography where 512-bit is not enough like RSA-PSS. If XOFs were available at that time, the proof of security of RSA-PSS will be much easier to show. That is huge where did you see that?

Comment: Are you asking _how_ it can do it as in the title, or _why_, as in the body?